# Set Visualforce Picklist value from custom controller

Tags: apex, dynamic-visualforce

i want to disply picklist value based on query value in my controller.
but its display nothing . the code is like:

```
<apex:page controller="Pre_process2">
<apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock title="Pre Process Payroll">
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" showHeader="false" >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Period Code" for="accts"></apex:outputLabel> 
        <apex:selectList id="PeriodCode" value="{!PeriodCode}" size="1" title="Period Code"> 
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!PeriodCode}"></apex:selectOptions> 
        </apex:selectList> 
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
 </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

the controller is:

```
public with sharing class Pre_process2 {
public String PeriodCode {get; set;}

 //public visualforcepage_picklist(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) 

//=============================== get picklist value for Period Code ================================== 
 public List<selectOption> getPeriodCode() 
 {        
    List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>(); 

    options.add(new selectOption('', '- None -')); 
    List<aggregateResult> results = [SELECT  Period__r.name FROM HREMPASSIGNMENT__c group by Period__r.name];
    for (AggregateResult ar : results)
    {
        string name = string.valueOf(ar.get('Name')); 
        options.add(new selectOption(name, name)); 
    }
    return options;    
 }}
```

do i miss something?

thanks and regards

Willy

Comment: Are you sure you are getting results in your query?

Comment: Can you please try with changing string name Periodcode to any other name.

Comment: @Tushar, yes i got result from my query.

Comment: @Kiunx Maybe it's related to the sharing rules on the object ?

Answer (score 3):

You have a string variable `PeriodCode` and a method `getPeriodCode` of return type `List<SelectOption>`. This is confusing and not a good practice.

I just changed the String variable name and it worked for me. Here is what I changed.

Class:`public String PeriCodeStr {get;set;}`

VF: `<apex:selectList id="PeriodCode" value="{!PeriodCodeStr}" size="1" title="Period Code">`

**PS: Experts in this community can explain better this behavior, I do not fully understand this.** According to my understanding we have two same `get` methods with different return types. So either this should not allowed to be saved and compiled. If it is saved then it should work properly??

Answer (score 0):

In your loop change this

```
string name = string.valueOf(ar.get('Name')); 
options.add(new selectOption(name, name));
```

To

```
Id id = (Id) ar.get('id'); 
string name = string.valueOf(ar.get('Name'));
options.add(new selectOption(id, name));
```